# Magento : install and config Atos module

Tags: php, magento, module, installation, magento-1.8

I'm new to magento. I had an error after installing (successfully) 3 `atos`  modules :

> Atos Sips Pro
>
> ATOS/Sips extension
>
> Quadra Extensions

```
Fatal error: Class 'Quadra_Atos_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Fieldset_Demohint' not found in /myprojectfolder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 590
```

The error is shown when i try to access Atos config (`System > Configuration > Atos`)

I have checked and the class isn't there.

Any ideas about what can be causing the problem?
The version of magento is 1.8

Comment: If the class isn't there, then there is a problem with the extension.  Give the extension developer a support ticket.

Comment: I found that there is a class named `Mageho_Atos_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Fieldset_Demohint` but i can't find from where it's calling the first class `Quadra_...`